# Access to containing class object within a struct

Tags: c#, struct

I need to access the containing class object from within a struct.  Is there a way for the struct to access the "this" member of it's containing class?

I've tried passing this into the struct, but it obviously doesn't work because at the time of field initialization I don't have access to the "this" keyword in the containing class.  I don't want to pass "this" in using the constructor of the containing class either.  I need to be able to pass it in during field initialization or work it out inside the struct.

I've seen some mentions of TypedReference, but not sure where to go with it.

The general idea of what i'm trying to accomplish is:

```
public class Test
{
     internal StructType<Test> _fieldName = new StructType(this);
}

public struct StructType<ParentT>
{
     public StructType(ParentT parent)
     {
          _parent = parent;
     }
     internal ParentT _parent;
}
```

Comment: So what problem are you having with the above code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The problem is that the "this" is not available during field initialization.  Apparently field's are initialized before the constructor, so "this" is only accessible after the constructor has initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `this` for field initialization, so you'll have to initialize in the constructor. Something like:

```
public class Test
{
    internal StructType<Test> _fieldName;

    public Test()
    {
        _fieldName = new StructType<Test>(this);
    }
}

public struct StructType<ParentT>
{
    public StructType(ParentT parent)
    {
        _parent = parent;
    }

    internal ParentT _parent;
}
```

As for "containing class object", there is no such special concept in C#. If you want an object to hold a reference to another object, you add a property of field and point it at the child object. If you want the child object to know about it's parent, well then you have to do that explicitly yourself by giving a reference to the parent to the child (in the constructor, for instance).

Comment: i don't want to pass "this" using the constructor.  The classes isessentially a form that could have many fields that would all need to be set in the constructor.  For clarity and to hopefully minimize errors, I don't want to require that the fields are set in the constructor.  I really need a way to work out the containing class from within the struct itself.

Comment: There is no such concept in C#. They are only two classes which are not related to each other in any special way. You should really revisit this design to not require such an unusual construct.

Comment: @Lostinthegame: To echo what John said, you can't. And to need to do such a thing suggest something else is up with your design. There aren't too many cases where something like this is necessary, but without more context, it's hard to say what your best solution might be. If you could have all your fields implement a single interface, you might be able to use a method in that interface to set the parent and then in your constructor just loop over all the properties that implement the interface, but that seems a bit wonky.